# Projection in Relational Algebra

Tags: database, projection, relational-algebra

There is a table called Person which has name, age, weight columns.

```
name: a, b,c,d,e

age: 34,21,23,34,12
```

**How can I use relational algebra to project the names that are ages 34?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I remember relational algebra correctly it should be something like this:

```
π name (σ age = 34 (Person))
```

where π is projection and σ is selection. This would be equal to `select name from Person where age = 34`in SQL and can be read as *from Person select relations where age is 34 and show name.*

The formatting options here are rather limited so it doesn't quite look like it should...